# Running MySQL Query in Wordpress Causes HTML Markup to Disappear?

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress

We're having an issue adding MySQL queries to our page. It seems that whenever something is run at the top of the page, **the rest of the markup and php functions to follow don't show up/aren't run.**

Here's a sample query that causes this issue:

```
global $wpdb;

$add_query = "CREATE TABLE thetesttable
        (
           id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
           product VARCHAR(50)
        )";

$wpdb->query($add_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Loading the page once results in a blank page.

The second time, we see `Table 'thetesttable' already exists`, which means that our queries are getting through.

There are no other errors on the page or anything else detected by Google Chrome.

What could be causing this problem?

Many thanks,

Justian Meyer

Comment: What response did you expect? First time create a tables, second time says it's already exist and that's error.

Comment: @RRStoyanov: Please read the full question. It's not about the error received in creating the table a second time. That was a test to determine if our queries were working. The issue is that our page markup doesn't make it through to the page viewer.

Comment: I would go with `error_reporting(-1);` first than

Comment: @RRStoyanov: PHP isn't throwing any errors.

Comment: error reporting should display all errors and if you can see if the script is terminated somewhere by some error. just for example, in a project of mine, I setup error_reporting to false and in same time I log errors. When error occurs, I say white screen and nothing else,  but when I check the error log... I see there was error. If you 100% that your script is error free and/or you don't have suppressed error displaying, than ok... everything that I assume by now is wrong.

Comment: @RRStoyanov: Our scripts are fine. Once we remove the line `$wpdb->query(...);` everything displays fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your query is returning 0 which is interpreted as false in your statment:

```
$wpdb->query($add_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

From the [`wpdb` class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database):

> The function returns an integer
>   corresponding to the number of rows
>   affected/selected. If there is a MySQL
>   error, the function will return FALSE.
>   (Note: since both 0 and FALSE can be
>   returned, make sure you use the
>   correct comparison operator: equality
>   == vs. identicality ===).

What you should do is something like:

```
$result = $wpdb->query($add_query);
if ($result === false)
{
  die('Could not run query');
}
```

**Edit:** By the way, also note that you should not use `mysql_error()` like you do when you use the wpdb class. To get the last error, you can use `$wpdb->print_error();`.

Comment: @Justian Meyer See the first line: The result of your query is 0 so: `0 or die()` which is the same as `false or die()` so the script dies. As there was no error, `mysql_error()` is empty. Result: The script successfully dies with an empty error message on a successful query that returns 0.

Answer (score -1):

After all additional comments, than I suggest adding additional query which is

`SHOW TABLES LIKE 'thetesttable';`

Run the `CREATE TABLE` query if no results from above one and skip it if table exist.

Comment: Still doesn't address the question. It has nothing to do with creating tables. The code provided is only a sample. I mentioned the error produced to show that our query was successful in the previous page load.

Comment: Why not provide more code than? From what you give, there isn't errors. You say no errors, no errors, but actually your code is correct. I may continue throw you suggestions and ideas, and you can continue to throw back such answers and down votes. Not cool, not at all...

Comment: I have highlighted the problem I wish to address in my original question, above. The error I am trying to address does not have to do with the MySQL query or the errors it produces, but that it cuts off the rest of my code. This issue may be WordPress specific and may deal with how the global $wpdb variable handles the db.

Comment: @Justian Well... all my first suggestions was about php error handling. I will tell what I do in such situations. I `echo 'here';` after every function which I think may hold the bug. When I find the function I do the same inside it until I find it and fix it. Also, as I say... with more code it will be more easy too.

Comment: There is not really any added value in providing more code. I can tell you right now that `echo 'here';` after the query will not run correctly because this is the issue that I have mentioned above (see bolded text in original question). We seem to be getting nowhere with this. Thanks for your help, but I will wait for other respondents to help me with this issue.